# XSLT 2.0 generate ouput filename from xml

Tags: java, xml, xslt-2.0

I have a little problem. I have to product a HTML file from a XML file using XSLT. But the HTML filename is generated by XML content.
In my case i solved my problem as following:

```
public File GenerateHTML(File fileIn) {
    File xsltFile = new File(xsltfileString);
    File htmlFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "result.html");
    File htmlFileFinal = null;
    Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(fileIn);
    Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(xsltFile);
    Result htmlResult = new StreamResult(htmlFile);
    TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans;
    try {
        trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);
        trans.setParameter("filter_xml", filterXML);
        trans.setParameter("FileName", fileIn.getName());
        trans.transform(xmlSource, htmlResult);
        String outputFileName = (String)trans.getParameter("OutputFilename");
        htmlFileFinal = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + outputFileName + ".html");
        htmlFile.renameTo(htmlFileFinal);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.FATAL, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (TransformerException ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.FATAL, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return htmlFileFinal;
}
```

and in my XSLT i do :

```
<!-- general settings -->
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:variable name="filter" select="document($filter_xml)/Filtre/Bloc5" />

<!-- transformation body -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="OutputFilename" select="concat(cac:ContractDocumentReference/cbc:ID, '_', cbc:ID, '_', translate(cbc:IssueDate, '-', ''))" />
[...]
```

This solution works, but i asked myself if it is optimized or if there is a trick in XSLT to generate a dynamic output filename ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well with XSLT 2.0 you can certainly create result documents with names respectively URLs based on XML input values e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document href="{root/foo/bar}.xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

You can also start with named template e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="doc('input.xml')"/>
  <xsl:result-document href="{$doc1/root/foo/bar}.xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc1/node()"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

although I am not sure how that fits in with the JAXP transformation API you use.

Comment: i asked myslef if there is a trick to easily transform a XML document into a HTML document where HTML'filename has been generated from the XML content.

Comment: It's not a trick: Martin showed you how to do it. What your code is doing I can't start to understand. trans.getParameter() shouldn't return anything the way you appear to be using it.

Comment: @ginogure, my code sample creates a result document where the name is constructed from the result of evaluating the XPath expression `root/foo/bar` to an imaginary input document with those elements and the string `.xml`. So adapt that path expression to fit your input document and you have right way. Or post your input sample and tell us which part of it is supposed to define file name.

Comment: Ok, apologies, it was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid the for-each altogether.
... from a working xslt.

```
<xsl:template match="EXTRACT-DATASETS/SUBSET">
...
...
<xsl:result-document href="{$filename-stub}.ctl">
...
...
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

This will generate a file for every match it finds. The variable filename-stub is calculated within the main template. No for-each needed....